# Use different view depending on object model database value in Django

Tags: python, django

I am launching a 2nd version of a project, and I want the users to be able to upgrade to the new format. It's not going to be a forced upgrade, so essentially, users will say "Make my page a V2 page". The URLs for their pages will stay the same.

I'd like to be able in the view to say:

```
def v1_page(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=page_id)
    if page.upgraded:
        # use the v2 view instead (which ends with a return render_to_response('v2_base_page.html', variables))
        v2_page(request, page)
    else:
        # load this page
```

Or am i going about it the wrong way?  I dont want a massive if/else statement.

Comment: Have you considered using redirect? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: @CeasarBautista - I'd really rather not make it be a redirect. I want the URL to stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function should return result of v2_page call:

```
def v1_page(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=page_id)
    if page.upgraded:
        return v2_page(request, page)
    else:
        # load this page
```